# Ubuntu VM python2 pathlib intstall error

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, python

so I'm trying some python 2 scripts in my Ubuntu VM. I installed python 2.
One of the scripts need the module `pathlib`.
Tried to install it but got a error message:

```
~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install -y python-pathlib
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 8632 (unattended-upgr)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I like to know that means and of course I like to know why this happened.
I'm grateful for any help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error because some other program is trying to update Ubuntu. When a command or application is updating the system or installing a new software, it locks the dpkg file (Debian package manager).

This locking is done so that two processes don’t change the content at the same time as it may lead to unwarranted situation and a possible broken system.

Read more [here](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/) about this error and how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks but after all methods tried out I still get the following error, which prevents me from installing pathlib:                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pathlib

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache search python-pathlib` ?

Comment: python-pathlib2 - Backport of the "pathlib" stdlib module (Python 2)

Comment: So try `sudo apt install python-pathlib2`